# Change "me" picture

Tags: contacts, huawei-ascend-ii

I literally have no idea how to change my "me" picture. I have tried many things, but none worked. I tried to add myself to my contacts, but that didn't work.

Device: Huawei Ascend II

Comment: We need some more information. Where do you see this "me" picture? Is it possible it's attached to your Google account?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google+ and have your Google account connected to your phone, your profile picture will be used as your "me" picture.